# NHibernate Exception: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have a table named as `User`. I declared my class as 
    `<class name="EETUser"  table="User">` it throws "Incorrect syntax near `User` keyword".

I then changed to `<class name="EETUser"  table="[User]">` 
This throws the error as Missing table: `[User]`.

I even tried

```
 <class name="EETUser"  table="'User'">
```

It throws the same exception.  `Table missing.`

Please help me out in this.

**NB: I cannot change the table name as this table is an existing one for years.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the schema name in your mapping class tag.
Also, remove the quotes around the table name.
If you cannot change the table name, you can create a synonym and map your entity to the synonym name.

```
<class name="EETUser"  table="User" schema="**table.schema.name**">
```